# ERROR: Cannot set priority of resourcemanager process 14923

Tags: macos, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am new in Hadoop.
I just installed hadoop in macOS and modified the following files:

```
   core-site.xml
   hdfs-site.xml
   mapred-site.xml
   yarn-site.xml
```

Then I formatted the namenode:

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

Then run the following command:

```
start-all.sh

Starting resourcemanager
ERROR: Cannot set priority of resourcemanager process 14923
Starting nodemanagers
localhost: ERROR: Cannot set priority of nodemanager process 15031
```

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Don't use start-all. Start the yarn node manager using its own start command

Comment: Please start one service at a time. Start the zookeeper first, then yarn and then hdfs.

Comment: 1) Edit the question not post an answer if you still get errors 2) Run something like `yarn nodemanager`, still don't use the respective start scripts. 3) There's actual log files that are being generated. Look for the real error there